# Using Python, stitch satellite images together, I have the polygons too

Tags: python, geometry, geospatial, polygon, satellite-image

I have satellite image1 and satellite image2, I have the polygons for them too ie. polygon1 and polygon2. How do I have them stitched into one image using python. They both have 4 layers saved as tiff files. I would wanna do these stitched for N number of images but first I need resolution for getting two stitched. Also the images/polygons can overlap too.

I tried getting the ratio between the overlaps dimensions and crop the images and concatenate them but they are not matching in the final stitched image.

Comment: Welcome to SO! What exactly have you tried so far? We're much more here to help with specific questions of the form "I tried X, but it did not do what I expect and instead resulted in an error!" accompanied by a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)